# c# - Object reference not set to an instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter

I'm trying to get tweets from twitter

But I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance

Code:

```
    public void Call_Tweet_Update()
    {
        var service = new TwitterService(Consumer_Key, Consumer_Secret);
        service.AuthenticateWith(Access_Token, AccessToken_Secret);

        var tweets = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions { Count = 200 });
        string[] twt_id = new string[50];
        long id = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int increment = 0;
        string twtid;
        string screenname;

        foreach (var tweet in tweets)
        {
            if (tweet.InReplyToStatusId.ToString() != "")
            {
                if ((tweet.User.ScreenName == "IIPL_LTD") || (tweet.Text.StartsWith("@IIPL_LTD")))
                {
                    string replyid = tweet.InReplyToStatusId.ToString();

                    while (replyid != "")
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            twt_id[i] = tweet.Id.ToString();
                        }
                        id = Convert.ToInt64(replyid);
                        var twt = service.GetTweet(new GetTweetOptions { Id = id });
                        //twtid = Convert.ToInt64(tweet.Id).ToString();
                        twtid = Convert.ToInt64(twt.Id).ToString();
                        //abc = twtid;
                        i = i + 1;
                        twt_id[i] = twtid;
                        replyid = twt.InReplyToStatusId.ToString();
                       // replyid = tweet.InReplyToStatusId.ToString();
                        // replyid = "";
                        increment = increment + 1;
                    }
                  }
                }
```

this is what the code terminated by Object reference not set to an instance

> Getting id as 38811592704 but the below line getting null value
>
> var twt = service.GetTweet(new GetTweetOptions { Id = id });

```
   while (replyid != "")
   {
       if (i == 0)
       {
          twt_id[i] = tweet.Id.ToString();
       }
       id = Convert.ToInt64(replyid);
       var twt = service.GetTweet(new GetTweetOptions { Id = id });
       twtid = Convert.ToInt64(twt.Id).ToString();
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the value of replyid if its null..

Comment: Run it in Debug and check which value is actually null. I guess we have to assume that the id is null, since the service shouldn't be if it was previously used...Check what is actually within replyid

Comment: I can get the replyid

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that ca cause you problem here is your class constructor

```
new GetTweetOptions
```

is giving you exception. Go to the constructor of this class and see what is creating error

Answer (score 1):

Debug your code Check at what Object you are getting this error
then try to resolve this error by using NEW key word to make a new instance of that object

for example suppose
var twt = service.GetTweet(new GetTweetOptions { Id = id });

Service in an object then u will have make a new instanse before using that